Exam class: \numpages wrong when enforcing an even number of pages
Goal: When using the exam class, I want to enforce the total page number to be even (by adding a blank page at then end if the regular page number is odd) and have a macro that gives the correct total (even) number of pages.
What I tried:

To enforce an even number of pages, I followed an answer on StackExchange by adding the following code line:
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\ifodd\value{page}\else\null\clearpage\fi}.
The code line adds a blank page at the end if the regular page number is odd.

To print the total number of pages, I use the macro \numpages{} provided by the exam class.


Problem:
\numpages{} is wrong (is smaller by 1) if the regular page number is odd and the code line above adds a blank page. (The macro is correct if the regular page number is already even.)
Minimum code example:
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

Number of pages: \numpages.

\begin{questions}
\question[1] Example question
\end{questions}

% Enforces an even number of pages:
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\ifodd\value{page}\else\null\clearpage\fi}

\end{document}

Solution ideas(?): Modify \numpages{} in a similar way as suggested in this StackExchange discussion, but make the modification dependent from whether a blank page was added or not. I was not able to achieve such a dependence.

I would just use the kernel's count from the previous run:
Number of pages: \PreviousTotalPages

results in 2 on the second compilation.

Simplest and shortest solution, thanks a lot! It does resolve the overall goal of providing a macro to get the total number of pages. It also seems that one can use this idea to fix \numpages{} via
\makeatletter\def\numpages{\@ifundefined{exam@lastpage}{\mbox{\normalfont\bf ??}}\PreviousTotalPages}\makeatother
All in all, I like this answer the most and plan to accept it.

In my redefinition of \numpages{} above, I just modified the original definition in the exam class by changing \exam@lastpage to \PreviousTotalPages and by surrounding it with \makeatletter...\makeatother (see also the discussion here at StackExchange).

I'm also not sure why \@ifundefined ...?? is used. In any case, your suggestion \let\numpages\PreviousTotalPages did unfortunately not work for me (gives 0 pages). However, I try to follow your recommendation (thanks!) in future to avoid two letter font macros.

@krfl I've deleted that comment. obviously I have, indeed, missed some subtlety here.

The exam class writes the value for \exam@lastpage at the “wrong” time, so your \AtEndDocument instructions comes after the annotation is made. You can fix it by rewriting the correct value at the right moment.
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}{%
  % ensure an even number of pages
  \ifodd\value{page}\else\mbox{}\clearpage\fi
  \if@filesw
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}% fix the wrong number we have now
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\exam@lastpage{\arabic{page}}}%
    \stepcounter{page}% to keep in sync
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Number of pages: \numpages.

\begin{questions}
\question[1] Example question
\end{questions}

\end{document}


A naïve way: check whether \exam@lastpage is odd and, in this case, add 1.
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  % ensure an even number of pages
  \ifodd\value{page}\else\mbox{}\clearpage\fi
}
\renewcommand{\numpages}{%
  \@ifundefined{exam@lastpage}%
    {\mbox{\normalfont\bfseries ??}}%
    {\ifodd\exam@lastpage\relax\inteval{\exam@lastpage+1}\else\exam@lastpage\fi}%
}% numpages
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Number of pages: \numpages.

\begin{questions}
\question[1] Example question
\end{questions}

\end{document}


Thank you for the answer. I also tried something similar as you but failed to come up with a working solution.  The advantage of your answer is that the exam class macro \numpages{} is giving now the correct number of pages (thus I don't need to use a different macro).

You may want to look into employing the pageslts package. Using this package for the task at hand may be overkill, but I think it's worth knowing about.

\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic} % it's important to provide a '\pagenumbering' directive

Number of pages: \pageref{VeryLastPage}

\begin{questions}
\question[1] Example question
\end{questions}

% Enforce an even number of pages:
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\ifodd\value{page}\else\null\clearpage\fi}

\end{document}


it's not compatible with current kernels, though. (at least, not fully compatible - bits of it still work.)

@cfr - Please elaborate. (I run MacTeX2024 w/ LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2, and I'm not aware of compatibility issues.)

texdoc lastpage bottom of page 1 in bold. (that's not a typo for pageslts.) related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/715096/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717530/. I think I originally got the information from Ulrike Fischer, possibly in a comment, but, if so, I can't find it to reference.

@cfr - Thanks, this is very helpful. I will admit to never having had a reason so far for using the pageslts package along with \pagenumbering{fnsymbol}. (It's always been \pagenumbering{arabic} for me... Boring...) I'll keep my fingers crossed, naturally, that the package author will find the time to update their packages to handle the latest kernel versions.

I suspect I either tried to use the package in an answer where I couldn't make it work or got told off by Ulrike for using it in some answer where it did work, because I don't think it was causing issues for me either.

Thank you for this interesting answer. For me (TexLive), it worked well.
